How to implement Django WebSockets?
I'm trying to create a simple Django app, using websockets for sending data.
According to the documentation:

I've added 'channels' in settings.py's INSTALLED APPS:

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "channels",
    "serial_mouse",
]

ASGI_APPLICATION = 'mouse_serial.asgi.application'


Created asgi.py file, to configure ASGI:

import os
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from serial_mouse import routing

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mouse_serial.settings')

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': get_asgi_application(),
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})



Set up routing.py for websockets:

from django.urls import path
from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    path('ws/serial/', consumers.SerialConsumer.as_asgi()),
]


Implemented the WebSocket consumer in the newly created consumers.py:

import json
import asyncio
import os

import serial
import cv2
import time
from django.conf import settings
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from .models import Capture, MouseData


class SerialConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(args, kwargs)
        self.serial_task = None

    async def connect(self):
        await self.accept()
        self.serial_task = asyncio.create_task(self.read_serial())

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        self.serial_task.cancel()

    async def receive(self, text_data):
        data = json.loads(text_data)
        if data['action'] == 'capture':
            self.capture_image()
        elif data['action'] == 'mouse_move':
            self.save_mouse_data(data['x'], data['y'])

    async def read_serial(self):
        ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
        while True:
            line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').strip()
            await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'message': line,
            }))


    @staticmethod
    def capture_image():
        cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        ret, frame = cam.read()
        if ret:
            captures_dir = os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'static', 'captures')
            if not os.path.exists(captures_dir):
                os.makedirs(captures_dir)
            filename = f'capture_{int(time.time())}.jpg'
            filepath = os.path.join(captures_dir, filename)
            cv2.imwrite(filepath, frame)
            Capture.objects.create(filename=f'captures/{filename}')

    @staticmethod
    def save_mouse_data(x, y):
        MouseData.objects.create(x=x, y=y)


Implemented views.py functions:

from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Capture, MouseData

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'serial_mouse/index.html')

def view_data(request):
    captures = Capture.objects.all()
    mouse_data = MouseData.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'serial_mouse/view_data.html', {
        'captures': captures,
        'mouse_data': mouse_data
    })


Updated index.html to use WebSockets:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mouse Serial App</title>
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'styles.css' %}">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <a href="/">Home</a>
        <a href="/view_data/">View Data</a>
    </nav>
    <button id="capture-btn">Capture</button>
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            console.log("Index.html script loaded.");

            const captureBtn = document.getElementById('capture-btn');
            const socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/serial/');

            socket.onopen = function() {
                console.log("WebSocket connection established.");
            };

            socket.onerror = function(error) {
                console.error("WebSocket error: ", error);
            };

            socket.onclose = function(event) {
                if (event.wasClean) {
                    console.log(`WebSocket connection closed cleanly, code=${event.code}, reason=${event.reason}`);
                } else {
                    console.error('WebSocket connection closed unexpectedly');
                }
            };

            document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
                const mouseData = {
                    action: 'mouse_move',
                    x: event.clientX,
                    y: event.clientY
                };
                console.log(`Sending mouse data: ${JSON.stringify(mouseData)}`);
                socket.send(JSON.stringify(mouseData));
            });

            captureBtn.onclick = function() {
                const captureAction = {'action': 'capture'};
                console.log(`Sending capture action: ${JSON.stringify(captureAction)}`);
                socket.send(JSON.stringify(captureAction));
            };

            socket.onmessage = function(event) {
                const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
                console.log(`Received message: ${data.message}`);
            };
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>

The app is starting, however I'm getting:
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/serial/.

WebSocket error:  
error { target: WebSocket, isTrusted: true, srcElement: WebSocket, eventPhase: 0, bubbles: false, cancelable: false, returnValue: true, defaultPrevented: false, composed: false, timeStamp: 261, … }

WebSocket connection closed unexpectedly

Same issue on Chrome as well. The app is working perfectly with Ajax. However it's failing to establish the connection with the websockets. Is there something that I'm missing?
I've tried with different browsers. I'm expecting for the app to work.

if you setup asgi server, then you need to install uvicorn or daphane to run the asgi server, i think you run the server with this command python manage.py runserver

I installed both, but I'm getting errors when launching the app. You don't run the server with python manage.py runserver, This is the standard way to run a Django application using the WSGI server. You have to use uvicorn APP_NAME.asgi:application --host 127.0.0.1 --port 8000, or daphne -b 127.0.0.1 -p 8000 APP_NAME.asgi:application. However I'm getting django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet. I've installed all dependencies and set the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE, but without result.
